# Oracle trigger to listen to alter table statements

Tags: oracle, triggers

Is it possible to create a trigger in Oracle that gets triggered if any alter operation happens across any table schema wide ?

if yes then any examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the create trigger [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/CREATE-TRIGGER-statement.html#GUID-AF9E33F1-64D1-4382-A6A4-EC33C36F237B) and search for the system trigger part. There are lots of examples on how to build system triggers and how they can fire on ddl